# Binding to specific rows and columns of a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a `ContainerViewModel` which inherits `Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive` and a `PanelViewModel` which inherits `Screen` and whose lifetime is controlled by `ContainerViewModel`

My `ContainerView` uses a `templated` `ItemsControl` to render a my `Collection<T>` managed by the conductor.  This view currently uses a `UniformGrid` control and the `items` are displayed in the order for which they are added to the `Conductor<T>.Collection` (`Items` are removed and added at `run-time` via an `event` which provides a `Position`).

I would like to switch to use a `Grid` with a predefined number of `Columns` and `Rows` as below:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
|      1     |      2      |      3      |      4      |
|     0,0    |     0,1     |     0,2     |     0,3     |
+------------------------------------------------------+
|      5     |      6      |      7      |      8      |
|     1,0    |     1,1     |     1,2     |     1,3     |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

The single number represents a `Position` and the `Points` \ `Coordinates` underneath the `Row Index` and `Column Index`.

I know I could do something like the following:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
                    Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                    Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- ItemTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

My issue with the above is that the `PanelViewModel` to be displayed as the `Content` needs a concept of the `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` properties for this to hook into.  I'm not entirely happy with this as I see it being the responsibility of `ContainerViewModel` to manage the positioning.

Is there a way I can achieve this where only the `ContainerViewModel` is aware of the `Position` concept?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `ContainerViewModel` to the `PanelViewModel` as a `parent` field and get `PanelViewModel` to pass the call back to `parent` when calling the getters of `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` properties by passing itself as the parameter to that call i.e. `parent.GetColumnIndex(this)` and `parent.GetRowIndex(this)`

While this means `PanelViewModel` now knows about `ContainerViewModel`, it achieves what you were looking for where the `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex`, while properties of the `PanelViewModel` are implemented in `ContainerViewModel`.

You could go further and abstract the method calls out to an interface so that the parent field is of the interface type rather than of type `ContainerViewModel` - it depends on how likely it is that `PanelViewModel` will be contained by other types.